# Based on tick values, how can I change width of my chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, angular6

On X-Axis I am trying to plot time based on hours, if the time period is 2 days, which makes 48 ticks on x-axis, in this case, all the labels are getting overlapped, and I am having problem displaying them. The question is how can i increase the chart container width on when there is an increase in ticks.

```
  <svg width="900" height="200" class="graph1" #lineChart id="line-chart" 
  (window:resize)="onResize()"></svg>

  const svg = d3.select(element),
  margin = { top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 60 },
  width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width - 20]);
  const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


  if (this.aggregate === 'Hour' || this.aggregate === 'Day') {
  x.domain(
    d3.extent(yData, function(d) {
      return d.valueTs;
    })
  );
  }
   y.domain([
  d3.min(yData, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  }),
  d3.max(yData, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  ]);

  if (this.aggregate === 'Hour') {
  g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeMinute.every(60)))
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'axis-title')
    .attr(
      'transform',
      'translate(' + width / 2 + ' ,' + (height + margin.bottom + 20) + 
  ')'
    )
    .style('text-anchor', 'end')
    .attr('fill', '#5D6971')
    .text('Time');
  }
```

This is what i am currently able to achieve!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5XIg.png

Comment: What about controling the number of x-axis ticks? Otherwise, if you want to display every tick number, you may end up with an extremely wide chart if there are many data points.

Comment: Yeah I will use scroll bar then, I am able to use that but in current scenario, I am not able to figure out how can I increase the chart based on number of ticks, suppose if ticks are less then if I am giving static width which is high, then the width between the ticks will be high, so how can I dynamically inrcrease the chart width.

Comment: Please check my answer - does it solve your problem? If not, it may be helpful if you could provide a working example, e.g. jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the width based on a static width and the length of your data, for example

```
var data = [{
    date: "1-May-12",
    close: "58.13"
}, {
    date: "30-Apr-12",
    close: "53.98"
}, {
    date: "27-Apr-12",
    close: "67.00"
}, {
    date: "26-Apr-12",
    close: "89.70"
}, {
    date: "25-Apr-12",
    close: "99.00"
}];

var width = 500 + data.length*50;
```

With data.length = 5 in this example, it would add 250px to your static length. Have a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jdt9k6w8/1/.

If you decide you want to change the number of ticks at your x-axis, this is a good post: http://www.d3noob.org/2016/08/changing-number-of-ticks-on-axis-in.html

Comment: That didn't work, I mean the width is still creating me a problem.

Comment: I thought that you want to dynamically set the width of your chart depending on the number of ticks/data points. This is what the above code is doing. You can adapt it by changing the static width and the factor of data.length. Maybe you could create a jsfiddle to illustrate your problem?

Comment: Sure @schustischuster, I will create a jsfiddle

Comment: Hey, I have tried with the method, you have told, and luckily it worked this time, the problem is width somehow, Thanks for the efforts. Schutischuster